# Why is the MediaElement not working for .MP4 files stored on my Google Drive?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui-community-toolkit

Audio Files (.MP4) files that are stored on my Google Drive are not being played when using the MediaElement of the MAUI Community Toolkit.

I am implementing the MediaElement functionality as follows:

In my XAML I have the following:

```xml
<toolkit:MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding MediaFile}" ShouldAutoPlay="True" /\>
```

The MediaElement is defined as follows in my xaml.cs cde:

```cs
public partial class Level3Page : ContentPage
{
    readonly Level3ViewModel _viewModel;
     
    public static MediaElement MediaControlA { get; private set; }

    public Level3Page()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        MediaControlA = mediaElement;
       
        BindingContext = _viewModel = new Level3ViewModel(this);
    } 
}
```

The following is my C# code in my ViewModel to get the file details from Google Drive and using the MediaElement Play method: `Level3Page.MediaControlA.Play()`:

```cs
request.Spaces = "drive";
request.Fields = "files(id,name)";
var result = await request.ExecuteAsync();
if (result.Files != null && result.Files.Any())
{
    var folder = result.Files.First();
    var fileName = "G010.mp3";
    //var fileName = GlobalVars.AudioFile + ".mp3";
    request = Service.Files.List();
    request.Q = $"mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name='{fileName}' and '{folder.Id}' in parents";
    request.Fields = "files(id,name)";
    result = await request.ExecuteAsync();
    if (result.Files != null && result.Files.Any())
    {
        var FName1 = result.Files.First().Name;
        MediaFile = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/" + result.Files[0].Id;
        Level3Page.MediaControlA.Play();
```

I get the following error from MediaElement:

> [0:] MediaManager: Error: Error codename: ERROR_CODE_PARSING_CONTAINER_UNSUPPORTED, Error message: Source error

I know that the value of `result.Files[0].Id` is correct, because  when I copy and paste the MediaFile URL contents into my web browser, the audio file plays without any issue.

Can someone please suggest what the issue could be?

Comment: "when I copy and paste the MediaFile URL contents into my web browser" do you get an HTML page that _contains_ a player for the file, or is the HTTP response Content-Type an audio file?

Comment: What happens when you `curl` that URL or open in incognito mode?

Comment: @gunr2171: The url shown is  https://drive.google.com/file/d/MY FILE ID.   I then get a black screen with audio functions in the middle.  When I press the play button, the audio file plays fine.   BTW, I do have to login with my Google drive credentials.

Comment: @orhtej2 : It works as above when used in incognito mode. Not sure what you mean by curl?

Comment: If you need to log in first then what your player is reading is login page not the file itself.

Comment: As the File Id is correctly identified, I am assuming my App is already logged in to the Google Drive. I am using a Service Account to bypass for the App user to login.  Therefore when the MediaElement  gets called the MediaFile should be pointing to the file location.